# Why in this exponential equation exponent goes in front in this situation?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have this equation:

$$5e^{-2x} = 20e^{-4x}$$

I was thinking it goes like this,
$$-2x\ln(5) = -4x\ln(20)$$
instead its,
$$\ln(5) - 2x = \ln(20) - 4x$$
where its easy to solve for $x$.

Thanks everybody for help! Been doing math 3 days straight i think its time for a break. Feeling so stupid now haha.

Lots of love from finland ! Solved

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b).$ Apply to $a=5,b=e^{-2x}.$

Comment: $\ln (5e^{-2x}) \ne -2x \ln 5$.   The power $-2x$ applies $e$ but *NOT* to the $5$ so you can't do the power rule of logs.  Instead you must do the multiplication rule $\ln 5e^{-2x} = \ln (5\cdot e^{-2x}) = \ln 5 + \ln e^{-2x}$ and now you can do the power rule (although you don't have to) an $\ln e^{-2x} =-2x \ln e = -2x \cdot 1=-2x$.

Comment: You might be confusing $5e^a$ with $5^a$.

Comment: Begin by cancelling by $e^{-2x} \ne 0$ on both sides !

Answer (score 1):

Working with algebraic expressions and manipulating equations is a fundamental skill.  A solution to your equation can look like this:

\begin{align}
5e^{-2x}&=20e^{-4x}\tag1 \\
e^{2x}&=4\tag2 \\
e^x&=\pm2\\
x&=\log\left(\pm2\right)
\end{align}

Here, we get from $(1)$ to $(2)$ by multiply both sides of the equation by $\frac15e^{4x}$.  Obviously, discard extraneous solutions as necessary.